# how to check the ip adress with a yaml file

Tags: if-statement, yaml

I would like to check an ip-adress with a yaml-file. Unfortunately I got some syntax errors when trying to run following code:

```
script:
    - echo "Checking if PXI-Testsystem is running.."
    - |
      exit_code=0
      if [ ping -n 1 10.54.10.10 | grep -q "ms" ]; then
        echo "FOUND"
        exit_code=$?
      else 
        echo "NOT FOUND" 
        exit_code=$?       
      fi
```

I get this error:

```
+ if [ ping -n 1 10.54.10.10 | grep -q "ms" ]; then
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
```

What is wrong with the syntax here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: pls see above the error message

Comment: This error is a windows powershell error message. So it seems your script is not executed in a `bash` (or any compatible shell) but in windows powershell ...

Comment: A YAML file does not execute code, the application that reads it does. That your code happens to be contained in a YAML file seems completely irrelevant to this problem. You should tag your question with the proper tag(s) of the technologies you use, because this is a problem of the semantics of the application you use, not a YAML problem.